# Convert several columns of data frame to numeric

Tags: r

I am reading a txt file into R and have several columns that should be numeric, but everything is interpreted as character. Now I would like to convert only a few columns within that matrix (I converted it to a matrix in a first step) to numeric, but I only managed to extract columns, but that way I got rid of the type matrix...

```
data <- as.numeric(data[,1])
```

Now, I've found similar questions here but none of the answers worked in the way that it conserved the type matrix.

For example, I've tried to store the affected columns in a vector and then perform the action on that vector with `lapply`

```
cols<- c("a","b","d")
data<- as.matrix(lapply(cols, as.numeric))
```

But this gives me only empty fields, and of course it only shows the columns I selected and not the rest of the matrix. I also got the error message

> NAs introduced by coercion

As a last step I tried the following, but I ended up having a list and not a matrix anymore

```
data[1:25] <- as.matrix(lapply(data[1:25], as.numeric))
```

What I would like to have, is a matrix where several columns (not just 1:25 as in my example above but rather, say, columns 1,3 and 6) are converted to numeric and the rest stays the same.

Does someone have an answer and maybe even an explanation for why the things I've tried didn't work?

Comment: In R, a matrix is a vector with dimension attributes. As such it can only have one data type. Since character is the most robust/general, your matrix is a character matrix. You probably want to use a data.frame, which is a type of list.

Comment: All columns in a matrix will be of the same class. You want a `data.frame`

Comment: ...I knew that it had to be such a stupid mistake....thanks!

Comment: But how do I define several columns, except for the d[1:10] way, but rather select columns 1,3 and 5 to be converted?

Comment: your title says data frame and example you are working is a matrix. convert into data frame and you should be OK.  ***Matrix*** A collection of homogeneous vector  elements in 2D ***Dataframe*** A list with possible heterogeneous vector elements

Comment: @User2017 Something like `sapply(data[, c(1,3,5)], as.numeric)` ?

Comment: This has bee answered several time on SO a simple search will get your answer. `cols = c(1, 3, 5)` # group the coloumns you would like to apply function    
`df[,cols] = apply(df[,cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character((x))`

Comment: Check 7.10 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f

Comment: @ira, yes that works, but it only gives me those columns then and not the rest of the matrix. ?

Comment: @User2017 You can write those columns into the original data.frame `data[, c(1, 3, 5)] <- sapply(data[, c(1,3,5)], as.numeric)`. Please note that the comment by JanLauGe regarding data types in matrix still apply.